# Exception for 32 bit number C++

Tags: c++, exception, double

Why do I get exception

`Unhandled exception at 0x00000001 in TestingCOA.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation (parameters: 0x00000008).`

when I try to work with a 4294967295 or higher number. On my machine `sizeof` double is `8bytes` which should be able to handle and work with`2^64 -1` number but it is generating exception for a 32 bit number, why is that?

```
int main()
{
  double n,remainderA;
  int AfterDecimal1[64],RemExponent1;

  cout<< "Enter number\n";
  cin>> n;

  remainderA=a-(int)a;

   HandleFractionNumber(remainderA,AfterDecimal1,RemExponent1);
}


int HandleFractionNumber(double remainder,int (&Goku)[64],int &RemExponent)
{
int x=0;
for(int i=0;;i++)
{
    remainder*=2;
    if(remainder>1)
    {
        remainder-=1;
        Goku[x]=1;
        x++;
    }
    else
        if(remainder<1)
        {
            Goku[x]=0;
            x++;
        }
        if(remainder==1)
        {
            Goku[x]=1;
            break;
        }
        RemExponent=x;
}
```

Comment: A 4294967295 bit number? If you mean you enter that as the value, [it works fine](http://ideone.com/jLRfnQ).

Answer (score 2):

Double does not work like that. It is a structure with fields and certain format (known as [IEEE double precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)). Not all 64 bits are available for the mantissa.

Yet, it should have eaten the number you mentioned (4294967295) at input. Are you sure this is what you put? Is the program you quoted - all there is?

Comment: I updated the question. I get exception when the given function is called.

Comment: AfterDecimal1 identifier not found. Anyway your exception is unrelated to doubles. It is probably in writing to this unknown AfterDecimal1

Comment: sorry I wrote the question in a hurry, thats why it had some mistakes. Some really really weird one.

Answer (score 0):

```
remainderA = a - (int)a;
```

On a 32-bit machine the result here is undefined if a > 429496725. Try printing out `remainderA`, I'm betting it's large, leading `HFN` to overrun the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You are running out of array boundaries.

x++ is done forever until it is greater than 64.

In code above, there is no reason for remainder to ever become one also. It is incorrect to compare a double with ==. It works reliably only for integer arithmetics.