# pthread_mutex_trylock() in Linux

Tags: c, unix, pthreads, mutex, errno

I am learning to use mutex in Linux programming. I came across trylock function, which first checks for the mutex if it is available it locks it otherwise, it return.

Now my question is:

- Does it return after reaching the end of function without executing the critical section, when trylock is called?
- Why doesn't it is printing `errno` in my code below?

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
pthread_t tid[5];

int i;

if(pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL))
    printf("Failed to lock the mutex\n");
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    if(pthread_create(&tid[i],NULL,func,&i))
        printf("Failed to create a thread\n");

    if(errno==EBUSY)
        printf("thread busy\n");

}

for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    if(pthread_join(tid[i],NULL))
        printf("Failed to wait for thread %d\n",i);
}

printf("All threads terminated\n");

return 0;
}

void *func(void * arg)
{
int i=*(int *)arg;

if(pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex)==0)
{
    sleep(5);
printf(" i is %d\n",i);

pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
else
    if(errno== EBUSY)
            printf("thread busy\n");
}
```

Sorry for format less code..

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pthread_mutex_trylock()` doesn't set `errno` - you simply use the return value:

```
int result = pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex);

if(result==0)
{
    sleep(5);
    printf(" i is %d\n",i);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
else
    if (result == EBUSY)
            printf("thread busy\n");
}
```

Comment: and If I want to that each thread should execute the critical section, I can enclose the trylock function inside a loop until result!=EBUSY.. Is this valid?

Comment: it does set errno actually http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.r12.bpxbd00%2Fptmtylk.htm

Comment: @Uzair: see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html  `pthread_mutex_trylock()` behaves as described by that POSIX spec (and my answer) on Linux; the IBM docs are apparently specifically for zOS.

Comment: @Alfred: no, do not do that.  If you would want the thread to loop until the mutex is free, then just simply use `pthread_mutex_lock()` which will perform the wait without needlessly burning CPU.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Please take a look at my this question also


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003434/exception-for-32-bit-number-c/14004850#14004850

Answer (score 1):

**Does it return after reaching the end of function without executing the critical section, when trylock is called?**

if `pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex)` is successfull (i.e. it returns 0) then first part (i.e. critical section) would be executed and function will return. if `pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex)` is unsuccessful(i.e. it returns -1) then else part would be executed and hopefully `thread busy` would be printed and function would return without executing critical section.

**Why doesn't it is printing errno in my code below?**

Either the call to `pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex)` is always successful, if you see all values of i (i.e. 1-5) being printed then this is the case. Or the errorno is not EBUSY you can check that by printing something before `if(errno== EBUSY)`.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for pthread_mutex_trylock says it returns the error code if locking the mutex cannot be done, it doesn't set errno to EBUSY. To get the expected result, you should do e.g.

```
int rc;
if((rc = pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex))==0) {
  sleep(5);
  printf(" i is %d\n",i);

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
} else {
  printf("thread busy: %s\n", strerror(rc));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No Nos.  No.   You have confused return value, with errno.   Errno, is handled in threads via the precompiler doing (*errnoAddress), so, yes, there is a errno per thread.    You should also NEVER use strerror(), as it's a security hole. That is another discussion.   But, here is your code using errno.

```
#include <errno.h> /* usually */ 
int rc;
if((rc = pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex))==0) {
  sleep(5);
  printf(" i is %d\n",i);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
} else {
  int e = errno; 
  printf("thread busy: %.64s\n", strerror(e)); 
  /* strerror is a security hole, print %d, and call it done.   */
}
```